# UITableViewCells not appearing initially

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have three UITableViews that should look identical.  Each is placed inside a different subview of a UIScrollView.  As I scroll, I can see each table.  The first table appears perfectly.  However, only the background color shows for the second and third tables.

tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is being called for every row for each table, where I insert a subview into the cell's contentView.  The subview has already been created before this method is called and is reused across the three tables for a given row (in an attempt to make tables look identical).

I made two interesting discoveries:

- Although the cell doesn't show initially, it will appear after scrolling to hide the row and then show it again.
- When the cell appears after scrolling, it has been moved from another table.  It no longer appears in the table where it had been showing.

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PlotCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlotCell" owner:self options:nil];

        if ([nib count] > 0)
            cell = self.plotCell;
        else
            NSLog(@"Failed to load AlertCell nib!");
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    ResultSet *rs = del.resultPlots;

    CPTGraphHostingView *cellPlotView = [rs.hostingViews objectAtIndex:row];
    cellPlotView.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;

    cellPlotView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;    
    [cell.contentView insertSubview:cellPlotView atIndex:0];

    return cell;
}
```

cellPlotView refers to the subview already created.

Any idea how to fix this so I can see all my tables correctly showing as I scroll? It's as if the cells can't reuse content. Thanks.

Comment: Do the three table views use this same implementation ?

Comment: yes, they use the same implementation

Comment: View can have only one superview. So create 3 identical CPTGraphHostingView views.

Comment: Don't you need to compute a correct array index based on `row` value ? I mean cell for first row of each table isn't source array index 0 each time, is it ?

Comment: @Vince first row for each table always uses index 0

Comment: @Roman This makes perfect sense.  If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View can have only one superview. So create 3 identical CPTGraphHostingView views.